# Почему фильтр ищет только по числам? VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Почему данный фильтр, с помощью v-model, фильтрует массив terminal исключительно по числам ( если буду вводить символы - ничего не находит )?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на скриншот кода](https://monosnap.com/file/GQh7FG3BxDWTXg85YmYzOWL3Gu9cjd)

Comment: Весь касающийся вопроса код должен быть прямо в вопросе и текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Вопросу минус за оформление: код прикладывают текстом, а не картинками. Перезалил на хостинг so, чтобы хоть что-то осталось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте что-то типа: `return el.terminal.some(item => item.match(this.filterTerminal))`